# Telethon - "Future exception was never retrieved" on disconnect

Tags: telethon

I have the following small TelegramClient app which I need to run continuously. Problem I am having is that when the internet disconnects, I get the error (image attached), "Future exception is never retrieved" and the application dies completely. How can I ensure that my application keeps running even if this disconnection happens? Many thanks for help

[image]

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

#api_id, api_has, chatIdToUse defined here

with TelegramClient('myusername', api_id, api_hash) as client:

    #https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chatIdToUse, pattern=r'(HELLOWORLD)'))
    async def handler(event):
        print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print('Received message')

    try:
        print("Running client until disconnected...")
        client.run_until_disconnected()
    #tried adding this doesn't work
    except NameError as err:
        print("TelegramClient exception:", err)
    finally:
        client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Note that `NameError` won't catch the `ConnectionError` that it gets raised, if any.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is using `NameError` instead of `ConnectionError` to catch the error as Lonami said in the comment.

secondly the error is telling you that telethon tried to reconnect 5 times (which is the default) but couldn't reconnect in those 5 times so it raised an exception.

You could either except `ConnectionError` or if you want to make your bot run longer you can increase the number of reconnects and the delay between them. So an example would be

```
client = TelegramClient("session", api_id, api_hash, connection_retries=sys.maxsize, retry_delay=10)
```

which would almost reconnect forever.